# Do we need to synchronize add() method this class?

Tags: java

If this class is used in multi-threaded environment and say 100 threads calling this method at same time .

Case 1 : instance method

```
public class test {

  public int add(int a , int b ){

    return a+b ;
     }

}
```

case 2:  static method

```
public class test {

  public static int add(int a , int b ){

    return a+b ;
     }

}
```

Please answer both cases .

Comment: can u please understand the intent - grammar is not important here.

Comment: it's not grammer.. it's SYNTAX!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using any state/instance variable you do not need to `synchronize` the method or the object.

*A friendly suggestion:* make the method static. Ans call it on the class.

Comment: Thanks for reply .But a moron from IBM started to synchronize it ;)

Comment: Please don't blame the whole company because a few made a blunder... IBM releases awesome codes... they have some of the best computers engineers. If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as answered by clicking on the up-tick next to this answer. [See here how](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). If you liked the answer, you may also up-vote by clicking on up arrow next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It does not need any synchronization because all the variables are local. i.e, no variable is actually shared between any of the callers.

If you did this, you would need sync because var c is shared. Before c was retrieved in the final 'return c' another thread may have already modified it.

```
public class test {

  int c = 0;

  public int addKeep(int a , int b ){
          c = a + b;
          return c;
     }
}
```

An other answer here says to make it static. Well, it depends on what you need to do. If the add(int a, int b) is a behaviour that subclasses could override, then keep it as an instance method. If it was part of a Math.class per-se, then make it static as it will likely never be needed to be over-riden.

Answer (score 0):

If object is mutable  and you are doing read-update operations then only we need to use synchronization block  for  getter and setters(i.e. mutating methods ).

Comment: you are answering your own question? :) Please edit your question if you have an extra info.